# Solve the given IVP through Cauchy-Euler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the IVP on the interval $\;(-\infty, 0)$:

$$4x^2 y'' + y = 0, \qquad y(-1) = 2, \qquad y'(-1) = 4$$

And the answer to the question (when $x < 0$) is:

$$y = 2(-x)^{1/2} - 5(-x)^{1/2}\ln x$$
I know that in solving this, I have to find the roots first. So, using the $y = x^m$ it will lead me to:

$$(2m - 1)^2 = 0$$

And we got a repeated root, therefore the general solution would be:

$$y = C_1 x^{1/2} + C_2 x^{1/2} \ln x $$

But I am having a problem when it comes to substituting the initial conditions. For obviously will get a natural logarithm of a negative number. Any ideas how can we solve this?

Comment: What do you mean to ask about? I don't see any question here...

Comment: @Amzoti, I have edited the question. And shared how I started solving it and what makes me stop.

Comment: @tomasz, I was still editing the question when you commented.S Sorry about that.

Comment: @user84275 I think something is not quite right with the solution you gave. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x^2*y%27%27%28t%29%2By%28t%29%3D0%2C+y%28-1%29%3D2%2Cy%27%28-1%29%3D4) doesn't seem to agree with the solution given.

Comment: @Amzoti True. My brain didn't keep $x$ as the independent variable.

Comment: @Daryl, but I think that it is really the general solution of the equation.

Comment: @Daryl, you are actually right. I recheck the equation and I forgot to put 4 on the equation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Version 1 of the problem (Problem not written correctly)**

We are given:

$$\tag 1 x^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$$

Here we have the troublesome case of $x< 0$, so lets use a change of variables. First, lets rewrite $(1)$ as (just artificially renaming the variable name here, nothing else):

$$\tag 2 t^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$$

Now, lets do a change of variables by letting $x = -t$.

We have:

- $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{dy}{dx}$
- $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, so we rewrite $(2)$, as:

$$\tag 3 x^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (0, \infty),~ y(1) = 2, ~y'(1) = 4$$

As you can verify, it is still Cauchy-Euler.

Using $y = x^m$ and substituting into $(3)$, and solving for the characteristic equation yields:

$$x^2 y'' + y = x^2(m(m-1)x^{m-2}) + x^m = x^m(r^2 - r +1) = 0 \rightarrow r_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{2} \pm \dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$

From theory, this gives us a solution of the form:

$$y(x) = c_1 x^{1/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln x\right) + c_2x^{1/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln x\right)$$

However, now we can switch back to $x = -t$, so we have:

$$y(t) = c_1 (-t)^{1/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln (-t)\right) + c_2(-t)^{1/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln (-t)\right)$$

This can be written as:

$$y(t) = c_1 |t|^{1/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |t|\right) + c_2|t|^{1/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |t|\right)$$

Because we artificially changed variable names, we are free to change those back to the original and have:

$$y(x) = c_1 |x|^{1/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |x|\right) + c_2|x|^{1/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |x|\right)$$

where $x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$$

Next, we need to use the ICs and find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

$y(-1) = c_1 (1) \cos 0 + c_2 (1) \sin 0 = c_1 = 2 \rightarrow c_1 = 2$

$\displaystyle y'(x) = -\frac{\sqrt{3} c_1 (x^2)^{1/4} \sin(1/2 \sqrt{3} \ln(\sqrt{x^2})))}{2 x}+ \frac{(c_2 x \sin(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \ln(\sqrt{x^2})))}{(2 (x^2)^{3/4})}+\frac{(c_1 x \cos(1/2 \sqrt{3} \ln(\sqrt{x^2})))}{(2 (x^2)^{3/4})}+\frac{(\sqrt(3) c_2 (x^2)^{1/4} \cos(1/2 \sqrt{3} \ln(\sqrt{x^2})))}{2 x}$

So, $y'(-1) = 0 + 0 - \dfrac{1}{2}c_1 -\dfrac{3}{2}c_2 = 4 \rightarrow c_2 = -\dfrac{10}{\sqrt{3}}$

Our final solution is:

$$y(x) = 2 |x|^{1/2} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |x|\right) -\dfrac{10}{\sqrt{3}}|x|^{1/2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln |x|\right)$$

Notes for OP:

- This is a nasty problem, made tons of algebra errors.
- Make sure you verify $y(-1) = 2$.
- Make sure you verify $y'(-1) = 4$.
- Make sure you verify $y(x)$ satisfies $(1)$ by substituting back into it.

**Version 2 of the problem (problem updated by OP)**

We are given:

$$\tag 4 4x^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$$

Here we have the troublesome case of $x < 0$, so lets use a change of variables. First, lets rewrite $(4)$ as (just artificially renaming the variable name here, nothing else):

$$\tag 5 4t^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$$

Now, lets do a change of variables by letting $x = -t$.

We have:

- $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{dy}{dx}$
- $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, so we rewrite $(5)$, as:

$$\tag 6 4x^2 y'' + y = 0,~ x \in (0, \infty),~ y(1) = 2, ~y'(1) = 4$$

As you can verify, it is still Cauchy-Euler.

Using $y = x^m$ and substituting into $(6)$, and solving for the characteristic equation yields:

$$4x^2 y'' + y = 4x^2(m(m-1)x^{m-2}) + x^m = x^m(4r^2 -4 r +1) = 0 \rightarrow r_{1,2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$$

So, we have a double root and the general solution can be written as:

$$y(x) = c_1x^{1/2} + c_2 x^{1/2} \ln x$$

Using the same rationale as version 1, with $x = -t$ and going back to the original variable names, we can rewrite this as:

$$\tag 7 y(x) = c_1|x|^{1/2} + c_2 |x|^{1/2} \ln |x|$$

with, $~ x \in (- \infty, 0),~ y(-1) = 2, ~y'(-1) = 4$

Using the IC's, we have:

$y(-1) = c_1 = 2$

$y'(x) = \dfrac{x(c_2(\ln x^2 +4) + 2 c_1}{4(x^2)^{3/4}}$, so

$y'(-1) = -\dfrac{c_1}{2} -c_2 = -1 -c_2 = 4 \rightarrow c_2 = -5$

So, our solution is:

$$y(x) = 2|x|^{1/2} - 5 |x|^{1/2} \ln |x|$$

Verifications:

- $y(-1) = 2$ (check)
- $y'(-1) = 4$ (check)
- $4x^2 y''+y = 4x^2\left( \dfrac{5 \ln x^2 -4}{8 (x^2)^{3/4}}\right) + \left(2|x|^{1/2} - 5 |x|^{1/2} \ln |x|\right) = 0$ (since x is real, check)

Lastly, since we are restricted to $x \in (-\infty, 0)$, this solution can be rewritten as you have shown it as:

$$y(x) = 2(-x)^{1/2} - 5 (-x)^{1/2} \ln (-x)$$

Comment: Nice write up! (And thorough, too!)